# Stopping an azure function after it is finished

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

We have a deployment script which deploys our function to a deployment slot, then stops the old function, starts the new and swaps the slot.

The main issue is about stopping the old function which we achieve via azure cli:

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name func-$prefix-toolset --resource-group rg-$prefix --settings AzureWebJobs.SyncDirtyJob.Disabled=true
```

While this stops the function as required, it also causes exceptions: ("a task was cancelled")

> Exception while executing function: Functions.ServiceBusHandleSyncQueue Result: Failure
> Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
> ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
> ...

Now we want to make sure that our function runs until finished and is stopped afterwards (and not just killed). The function is triggered by a queue so it is stopped once correctly finished.

Can this be done by azure cli or do we have to implement our own "gracefully shutdown" - method (e.g. through an app setting)?

Comment: Have you tried to make next steps: Pause Azure Functions host -> stop Azure Function -> Resume Azure Functions host? Or it will not fit your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

> By using the  `Durable Functions extension`  for Azure Functions to ensure that your function runs until finished and is stopped afterwards.

The Durable Functions framework checkpoints the progress of the current function instance each time you call await.

If the process or virtual machine recycles midway through the execution, the function instance resumes from the preceding await call.

> Can this be done by azure cli or do we have to implement our own "gracefully shutdown" - method (e.g. through an app setting)?

I do not find any `code/command` related to Graceful shutdown in `Azure CLI`.

You can implement the pattern in this example by using an orchestrator function. The orchestrator uses a  [durable timer](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers.md)  to request approval.

Thanks @[cgillum](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers.md) for the code.

The orchestrator escalates if timeout occurs. The orchestrator waits for an  [external event](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events.md), such as a notification that’s generated by a human interaction.

Thanks @[kAleksei](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview.md#pattern-3-async-http-apis)

> ```cs
>  [FunctionName("Function1")] 
>  public static async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context) 
>  {
>     await context.CallActivityAsync("Req", null);
>     using (var timeoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource())
>     {
>         DateTime dueTime = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddHours(72);
>         Task durableTimeout = context.CreateTimer(dueTime, timeoutCts.Token);
>
>         Task<bool> approvalEvent = context.WaitForExternalEvent<bool>("Event");
>         if (approvalEvent == await Task.WhenAny(approvalEvent, durableTimeout))
>         {
>             timeoutCts.Cancel();
>             await context.CallActivityAsync("Proc", approvalEvent.Result);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             await context.CallActivityAsync("Escalate", null);
>         }
>     } 
>   }
> ```